# Auto resizing div with max width

Tags: html, css, text, space

I'm trying to create a div for text that resizes the width depending on how much text is in the div, but also has a maximum width, thus splitting the text into multiple lines if it exceeds the max-width. The text does resize with one line of text and split when there's too much, but when there's more than one line a large space appears inside the div between the right edge of the text and the border.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="balloon">
  This is sample text. This is a second sentence.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.balloon {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 225px;
}
```

Here's a demo to demonstrate what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/oft3n5wg/

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Try to add text-align:justify to your class. Is that what you want?

Comment: **There's nothing wrong** in your example. What large space you're talking about?

Comment: *`If the amount of text exceeds the max-width, the text should split into multiple lines`* that's exactly what your example does.

Comment: No, I'm trying to remove the large space that appears when there's two lines. It's odd, because there's no margin or padding on anything.

Comment: @AlexSlack what large space? It's a square! Can you be more precise please?

Comment: I think because the next word is too large. Try adding a smaller word instead of 'second', like 'the', see if it still does that

Comment: OK, so part of it is an operating system difference. I was developing on Linux, and when I tested it on Windows just a minute ago, the space was much smaller. Still there, but smaller.

Comment: Thanks Abdul Ahmad. I suppose because the max width was already exceeded, it stays at that width even though it doesn't need to once the text splits. And thank you Roku for helping me with clarity. I'd still like to find a solution if I can, but now that I know that it would mostly be a problem for Linux users, I'm quite not as concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oft3n5wg/4/)

This is just because the first word on the 2nd line is too large to fit in that space your have highlighted in red. Replace the word "second" with "seco" and you'll see that it fits

you can add a `text-align: center` so that the space doesn't look as bad if you want, or do `letter-spacing: 1px` so there's more space between the letters and it will fill the white spaces a bit more

Comment: OK, thanks! Your help was greatly appreciated. The letter-spacing helps quite a bit.

Comment: If someone's post helps you, you should up-vote, and if it answers the question you should accept the answer

Comment: OK. I can't up-vote quite yet since I just joined stackoverflow, or else I would.

Comment: Ok no problem, my apologies if I came off a bit mean. I was busy with something else so wasnt paying full attention

Comment: No, you're fine. :) I'm just glad someone had an answer. I couldn't find anything that worked and it was driving me crazy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your content goes in here

The whole idea is specifying a max-width and also sett